# I don't know what this dimension means for a diode package drawing

Tags: diodes, symbol, packages

I came across this case number and dimension for a diode, a D1NK60, that I would like to use:

AX057: 3.0 × φ 2.6(mm)

The data sheet is [here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/366/shindengen_F072_14a_pdf-2323367.pdf) (document page 31, PDF page 18).

I don't know what phi represents. Google was not much help.

[image: screenshot from linked document showing the relevant page]

Comment: FYI there's some relevant explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Symbol) on the Wikipedia page for that symbol, regarding font limitations etc.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The package (not including leads) is a cylinder 3.0mm in length and 2.6mm in diameter (⌀). Note Mattman's comment on the character identity. The careful engineer or typesetter will not confuse any of these different characters:
Ø ⌀  ∅ ⵁ Φ Ф.

The Japanese language paper info I have also shows the leads are 29mm +/-1mm long and 0.6mm diameter. The tolerance on body diameter and length are +/-0.1mm.

Answer (score 2):

Diameter is a slashed 0: Ø, not the Greek letter phi φ.

Comment: Yes. +1 In some fonts phi is very similar but the line is typically vertical not slanted.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It could with more context.

Comment: I agree +1 but it was written in the pdf file as φ

Comment: Diameter is neither slashed zero nor slashed letter O. It is a slashed circle.

Answer (score 1):

Usually "Φ" denotes *diameter*. That's the uppercase version of "φ". I think it's a typo, where they got the case of a Greek letter wrong.

Answer (score 0):

φ  means diameter

unless used for phase , φ

Note that I copied the character directly from the datasheet.  but because the real reason has to do with unicode font substitution

The author wanted **Ø** and saw [image] but it got **phi, φ** maybe from a font translation in our pdf browsers.

You often see W for Omega \$\Omega\$ in PDF files for a similar reason.